# How to get access to the TabHost from activity, that is't one of the tabs?

Tags: android, menu, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have TabActivity **MainTab** and all my Activities extend **BasicActivity**. In **BasicActivity** I made same menu for all Activities.

How to get access to the TabHost from **BasicActivity** on item menu click when Activity is't one of the tabs?

Now I am using TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
BUT it will work only when activity is one of the tab.

```
public class BasicActivity extends FragmentActivity {   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_main, menu);
    return true;
}
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()){
     case R.id.stad:
       TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
       tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
     break;
     default:
        return false;      
   }
   return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "singleton" in your TabHost and access it with TabHost.getTabHost()

```
private static TabHost tabHost;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    tabHost = this;
    ...
}

public static TabHost getTabHost() {
   return tabHost;
}
```